# C# OpenGL Macros Missing?

Tags: c#, opengl, macros

I am using Pencil.Gaming as the C# Wrapper for the OpenGL functions. I wanted to write a quite application to get the OpenGL renderer and version information but I can't seem to find the Macros for these (GL_RENDERER and GL_VERSION).

Has anyone used Pencil.Gaming or another C# wrapper before and used these or similar macros? Where are they located? Or is there another way to get this information with the wrapper?

Here's the code I have so far:

```
using System;
using Pencil.Gaming;
using Pencil.Gaming.Graphics;

using GLubyte = System.Byte;

namespace C_Sharp_OpenGL
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (!Glfw.Init()){
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Could not start GLFW3");
                Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key to Continue...");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Environment.Exit(-1);
            }

            GlfwWindowPtr window = Glfw.CreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello Triangle", GlfwMonitorPtr.Null, GlfwWindowPtr.Null);

            Glfw.MakeContextCurrent(window);

            //Get Version Info
            GLubyte renderer = GL.GetString(GL_RENDERER); //Doesn't Work
            Glubyte version = GL.GetString(GL_VERSION); //Doesn't Work
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: C# doesn't have macros.

Comment: https://github.com/andykorth/Pencil.Gaming/blob/master/Pencil.Gaming/Graphics/GlEnums.cs#L6812 ?

Comment: @genpfault Brilliant thanks for your help!